# Rocket.Chat server shuts down and forgets settings

Tags: mongodb, rocket.chat

We installed an instance of Rocket.Chat server on an Ubuntu server machine. All worked fine. But every day in the evening the Rocket.Chat server end up working and forgets the url and mongo-db setting. Then I need to do again:

- `export ROOT_URL=http://your-host-name.com-as-accessed-from-internet/`
- `export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/rocketchat`
- `node main.js`

and the server runs. But every day in the evening we have the same problem.

Does anyone know the problem and has a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Adding as an answer so the question gets closed.

```
Disclaimer: I work for Rocket.Chat.
```

Why does the server end up working? Is there any information in the logs?

Also, since you are setting these variables in your shell session, they will be cleared on your next session. If you want them to be persistent, you must add in your /etc/profile... You can also reach us on demo.rocket.chat on channel #support or file an issue on github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you should create rocketchat service and enable this as your system startup process/services.

you can checkout video tutorial about how to create rocketchat service [here](https://youtu.be/G2J5Rd-5qbA)

```
ADD ROCKET CHAT SERVICE

gedit  /usr/lib/systemd/system/rocketchat.service

# Add following lines in this service file

[Unit]
  Description=The rocket chat server
  After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target nginx.target mongod.target
  [Service]
  ExecStart=/bin/node /opt/rocketchat/main.js
  StandardOutput=syslog
  StandardError=syslog
  SyslogIdentifier=ping
  User=root
  Environment=MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/rocketchat ROOT_URL=http://192.168.0.138 PORT=3000
  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target

systemctl enable rocketchat.service
systemctl start rocketchat.service
```